# Custom scss doesnt override bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, sass, nuxt.js

I Have a `global.scss` file that includes all of my custom `scss` files like so:

```
// global.scss

    // Variables & Fonts
    @import "variables";
    @import "fonts";
    
    // Components
    @import "components/navbar";
    
    // Bootstrap styles
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

But for some reason my `components/navbar` code is overwritten, I can only get them to work if I add `!important` to all of my properties.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

Since I import my components/navbar first then that file should have higher precedence over the bootstrap file, thus I don'get how bootstrap writes over my css rules.

The only way right now that I can increase my precedence would be to use `ID's` or `!important` but that would be a bit silly.

Comment: if you inspect the css rules in your browser do you see your rules show up but cancelled/crossed-out? If so, take a look at the rule that is taking effect and adjust your specificity to take precedence.

Comment: Shouldn't my components file have initial precedence since I import that first? The css rule is crossed out, thats why I say it is overwritten, The only ways I could think of increasing my precedence would be to change out my classes to Id's or to continue `!important` and that would be kind of silly.

Comment: try putting your custom styling after the bootstrap import, if that doesn't work then try to add more specificity (using nesting) to your custom rules until the addition takes precedence over the bootstrap rule.

Comment: Ah! Putting my bootstrap First and my custom component styles After works! 
I get it now. Overwriting, bootstrap comes first and then I overwrite them. what a silly mistake :P Yet the variables file seems to work either way, interesting.

Comment: Here is an article about CSS cascade: https://wattenberger.com/blog/css-cascade